# Read Nist Wav File in TIMIT database into python numpy array

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, speech-recognition

Is this possible?? I seem to be getting this error when using wavread from scikits.audiolab:

```
x86_64.egg/scikits/audiolab/pysndfile/matapi.pyc in basic_reader(filename, last, first)
     93             if not hdl.format.file_format == filetype:
     94                 raise ValueError, "%s is not a %s file (is %s)" \
---> 95                       % (filename, filetype, hdl.format.file_format)
     96 
     97             fs = hdl.samplerate

ValueError: si762.wav is not a wav file (is nist)
```

I'm guessing it can't read NIST wav files but is there another way to easily read them into a numpy array? If not, what is the best way to go about reading in the data?

Possibly rewriting the audiolab wavread to recognize the nist header??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Answer my own question because figured it out but you can use the Sndfile class from scikits.audiolab which supports a multitude of reading and writing file formats depending on the libsndfile you have. Then you just use:

```
from scikits.audiolab import Sndfile, play
f = Sndfile(filename, 'r')
data = f.read_frames(10000)
play(data) # Just to test the read data
```

Answer (score 2):

To expand upon J Spen's answer, when using [scikits.audiolab](https://scikits.appspot.com/audiolab), if you want to read the whole file, not just a specified number of frames, you can use the `nframes` parameter of the `Sndfile` class to read the whole thing. For example:

```
from scikits.audiolab import Sndfile, play
f = Sndfile(filename, 'r')
data = f.read_frames(f.nframes)
play(data) # Just to test the read data
```

I couldn't find any references to this in the documentation, but it is there in the source.

Answer (score 0):

In contrast to the above answers, there is another alternative way to read
audio files in multiple formats, e.g., .wav, .aif, .mp3 etc.

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import soundfile as sf
import sounddevice as sd
# https://freewavesamples.com/files/Alesis-Sanctuary-QCard-Crotales-C6.wav
data, fs = sf.read('Alesis-Sanctuary-QCard-Crotales-C6.wav')
print(data.shape,fs)
sd.play(data, fs, blocking=True)
plt.plot(data)
plt.show()
```

Output:

```
(88116, 2) 44100
```

[image]