# Cannot open WAV file in python using scipy.io.wavfile

Tags: python, scipy, speech-to-text

I'm trying to work with WAV files using scipy.io.wavfile but the file I want to read has headers inside of it (NIST). I tried deleting the headers (that was dumb), I tried using other libraries (wave), custom functions found online but It still doesn't work. I get "Not a WAV file."

The .wav files are from mocha-timit, a speech training corpus.

can someone help me out?

Thanks.

Comment: The error means the file is not a valid WAV file. mocha-timit uses some custom audio format, not WAV.

Comment: What can I read the file with?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some things you could try:

(1) Use `scikits.audiolab` as in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10187043/read-nist-wav-file-in-timit-database-into-python-numpy-array)

(2) Convert the wav format from NIST format to the standard RIFF format with a tool like `sndfile-convert` from ['libsndfile'](http://www.mega-nerd.com/libsndfile/) (You'll need to change the original file endings to .nist).

I got (2) to work on my own system and could read the files with `scipy.io.wavfile.read`